# removing security in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

i have developed application reading and adding the contacts by using PIM api but the problem is it is prompting 
allow application to use network and send or receive data?

allow application to read user data?
allow application to write user data?

It is prompting two times for read and write.

how to remove this and allow application to do everything without prompting?

Answer (score 1):

[Get](http://blog.javia.org/midlet-signing/) [your](http://www.spindriftpages.net/blog/dave/2006/06/18/midlet-jar-signing-a-tutorial-revised/) [MIDlet](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/wtk/demos/wtk-sign.html) [signed!](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=90552)